# How to open something cmd like?

Tags: command-line

I'm new to Ubuntu and I need a command line to follow a tutorial. How to do this?

I already tried searching for cmd but failed. Any one knows?

Please help me.

Comment: Can you elaborate what are you actually trying to do? What's your end goal?

Comment: I want to install a mail server to get my own mail domain

Comment: It's called `terminal` , press Ctrl+Alt+T to get to it. Also . . . maybe you should spent some time learning command line first, before trying to install mail server

Comment: I very much agree with @Serg on this. Simply following a tutorial on this will not be easy. There are a lot of things to consider before setting up a mail server. Even after you get through everything, it probably still won't work as most residential ISPs block port 25 and only allow business class customers to set up these servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy. The command line in Ubuntu is called Terminal. Search for Terminal in the Dash (at the top right) or press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: @Jane not that difficult, but a simple Google search would have given you the awnser faster

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `terminal`  - you can either type the name `terminal` into the search, or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>